# Why is my Java application not closing properly?

Tags: java, swing, applet, jvm, awt

I have a java application that loads and displays an applet on a JTabbedPane.  So basically the GUI is:

Applet --> JPanel(AppletStub) --> JPanel --> JTabbedPane --> JFrame

I already put this standard line in the JFrame class:

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

Here is my method in the JFrame class which is supposed to be called when the window is closed:

```
    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            setVisible(false);
            tabbedPane.stopAllApplets();
            dispose();
            super.windowClosed(e);
        }
    });
```

Then, in my Tabbed Pane class, I have an arrayList which manages the Applets:

```
ArrayList<PanelHolder> games = new ArrayList<>();
```

I loop through the ArrayList of JPanels like so:

```
public void stopAllApplets(){
    for (int i = 0; i < games.size(); i++) {
        games.get(i).stopGame();
    }
}
```

The stopGame() method in the JPanel class is quite simply:

```
public void stopGame(){
    game.stop();
}
```

Then in the JPanel class which implements AppletStub here is the stop() method:

```
public void stop() {
    if (applet != null) {
        applet.stop();
        applet.destroy();
        applet = null;
    }
}
```

However, whenever I close the applet, the JVM keeps running and hogging system resources.  I'm using a BootLoader that starts a JVM with the arguments:

```
javaw -Xbootclasspath/p:"/C:/Users/Username/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Game/build/classes/" -cp "." main.Main
```

Here is what my task manager looks like eventually after I run it a few times:

[image: Multiple JVM instances]

I'm obviously not closing my application correctly, any suggestions?

Comment: The only reason for the JVM not to exit is because there is a non-daemon thread still running

Comment: @MadProgrammer makes sense.  I'll check it out, thanks!

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).  Who wrote the applet?  You or someone else?  It seems as though the applet is creating non-daemon threads (but that's just a guess).

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your frame code:

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

By default it is WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE

Comment: Sorry, didn't mention that I already have that.  I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Have you tried going into debug closing the app and looking which thread remains running (has to be some non demon). That might give a hit why it is not closing.

Comment: That makes sense, I'll try that

Comment: Turns out it was a simple problem.  Just stupid that I wasted 2 hours on this.  Thanks though!

Comment: It is usually like that. Good luck with your work ;)